# Mail forwarding using apps script issue

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am forwarding the emails coming to my mailbox using the below apps script code.
The code works fine but when same subject line messages are grouped into one email it forwards older emails also. I am filtering the today's mails received 5 mins prior to the script execution[image].

```
     var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
     var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox newer_than:0d after:' + timeFrom);
```

I printed the date using the below line of code and it is giving today's date for the trail mails.Referring to the screenshot it is printing today's date for all three emails.

```
          var mtime =messages[m].getDate();
```

Appreciate suggestion and advise.

Comment: you aware that gmail natively supports forwarding right?

Comment: Yes but we have forwarding disabled in our organization